Is it possible to create 3D Building Configurator with Autodesk APS ? or Three.js is better?
I am a Three.js developer. I know 'thatopencompany' recently for ifc files (BIM) too.
We want to create a website like https://planner5d.com/.
I need some data of .ifc files like space, floors, lamp and electrical,... and of course, I need three.js features like texture and material and open to customize everything, drag and drop, and add different models like furniture, ...
How Can I do that?
What is the best choice?
Three.js
or
Autodesk APS
or
Xeokit
or
Thatopencompany
or
Speckle
?
We need to change textures, and materials, and replace objects like furniture for interior design,...
3D configurator 1
3D configurator 2
I want to create advanced 3D configurator for Interior design with high performance
Drag and drop,change textures,change objects in model
3D configurator 3
3D configurator 4
3D configurator 5

Asking recommendations on tools, libraries, etc. is off-topic on StackOverflow. Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]

@ParisaShahbazi Autodesk APS Viewer actually uses three.js in the background.  Albeit it's I think on version 71 (so ... code from back to 2015).  Pretty sure the guy that answered you below just used AI to generate a response, which wasn't actually helpful at all.  Anyway, I use three.js directly to add layers and such on the APS Viewer when there's not a supported way by their native functions.  I'm betting this would be a good place to start based on your question.  I have no knowledge of the others you asked about, however.

@MattH Thanks.So Which API in APS do I have to use? I faced with a lot of APIs.Do you mean we can change textures and use drag and drop and make everything custom in Autosedk APS? I can use ifc file data and good visualization like three.js at the same time with APS?which API?

@AhmedRamadan What do you mean by using Autodesk on the server side? And How Can we sync Autosedk APS and Three.js together? APS uses CW format but Three.js use glb mostly.

Do you know Which APIs of Autodesk APS are suitable for our purpose?

@ParisaShahbazi All of the viewer APIs are in the link below.  For example, you may be able to change the textures of things using the provided function, like viewer.setThemingColor.  Navigate to the API list under Viewing and under Viewer3d to see most of the functions you can deal with.  https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/
But first, you would need to first translate your .ifc file to SVF or SVF2, which you can follow this guide for using the model derivative APIS to do: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/

After that, I don't have experience with what you're asking about (drag/drop, moving models, "customizing everything", etc.), so you would need to explore that.  I suspect the that would need to be custom extensions and/or three.js work.  You would also need to determine if you need your objects saved in whatever configuration you choose, as the Viewer is intended to just be a viewer (not an editor).

Here are some resources that might help:

Check out these blog posts on Autodesk APS:
•   Dynamic Model Placement (https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/dynamic-model-placement)
•   Drag-and-Drop Models in the Viewer (https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/drag-and-drop-models-viewer)

Consider converting your IFC models using the Model Derivative (MD) API and viewing them in the APS Viewer. You can try this out using the free online version of the APS Viewer here (note that data is wiped after 30 days).

To explore the APS Viewer API, open the Chrome debug console while viewing your model. For example, you can click on a door and type NOP_VIEWER.getSelection(). Other useful methods include isolate(123), fitToView(123), and setThemeColor().


For your decision between Three.js and APS Viewer, consider the following:
•   Three.js is great for projects like an IKEA kitchen configurator, where the focus is on rendering and visual customization.
•   APS Viewer is better suited for projects that require sustainability calculations, BIM quality documentation (RVT, IFCs, PDFs of sheets, and assembly instructions) that may need to go to a general contractor (GC).

Both options will require some work, but the right choice depends on your specific goals and the complexity of your configurator.
FYI. I'm doing a talk at Autodesk University 2024 Oct 17th, that shows a floor layout configurator build with APS Viewer and uses AI to render the final result.
​
​AS2957 | Introducing AI Rendering
